# INTO OUTFILE query for export is not working on local drive

Tags: mysql, csv, mysql-workbench

**Using:**  MySQL Workbench

I am trying to write in to my MySQL Query to have the file automatically save using the current date (orders_20150214.csv), however even the basic save(no date) is not working, I keep getting a server refusal.

Code:

```
USE `databasename`;
Select   -- complex query from multiple tables -- 
-- Get Order data --

INTO OUTFILE 'E:\My Documents\2014-2015 Accs\ccccc\orders.csv'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '"'
ESCAPED BY '\\'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
```

Error:

```
Error Code: 1045. Access denied for user 'dddddd'@'%.dddddddd' (using password: YES)
```

I have also tried a number of variations of the above

```
USE `databasename`;
Select   -- complex query from multiple tables -- 
-- Get Order data --
FROM table_name  -- multiple tables --
INTO OUTFILE 'E:\My Documents\2014-2015 Accs\ccccc\orders.csv'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
```

I know MySQL Workbench has an inbuilt "save as" and I use it, however there are days where I want to run the query, and it autosaves.  I have a macro that retrieves data from .csv files and compiles to a running order book, I'd like to automate it further.

I have also tried:

```
INTO OUTFILE 'E:\\My Documents\\2014-2015 Accs\\dddd\\orders.csv'
INTO OUTFILE 'E:/My Documents/2014-2015 Accs/dddd/orders.csv'
-- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/select-into.html
```

I've read mixed messages as to whether I can do this programmatically to save on my local machine.  So it may not be possible directly through MySQL Workbench.

Please help :)

Comment: Remember:  you are communicating to a MySQL server possibly on another machine probably running as a different user.  Try saving the file in a place where the *server* has access to.  This might be as simple as sharing your local drive with the server, but a lot depends on the security environment you are working in.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I had wondered about the permissions of my folder. I am loathe to share my 'docs' folder, however I may create an indi folder somewhere else then for this.  I'll have to google.  Thank you.

Comment: Often, there is some sort of shared folder where you can create the file and then copy it to your local machine.

Answer (score 2):

I am pretty sure you're getting the 1045 error because your user account needs to be granted the `FILE` privilege in the MySQL server in order to even attempt `INTO OUTFILE` operations.

You, or your friendly local admin, can do that with a query like this.

```
GRANT FILE  ON *.* TO 'user'@'host';
```

The stuff Gordon mentioned is still true: The MySQL server will write the output file into its own file system, and the file it writes will be owned by it. You'll need to copy it.

If you're on a Windows system, you can try using the path to which the `%TEMP%` environment variable expands... for example

```
INTO OUTFILE 'C:\\Users\\MrsAdmin\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\orders.csv'
```

On a *nix system,

```
INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/orders.csv'
```

will do the same thing.  Then you can copy the file to wherever you need it written.

Comment: thank you.  I'll check my settings, and if it works, I'll come back & mark it as the answer, thank you for your time :D

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind that your MySQL server runs usually under a different account than your personal one (on Windows usually "Network Services"). This account doesn't have write access to "normal" folders. You can simply create an export folder and add "Users" with read/write access to it's ACL. That will allow the server to write files there then.